# Matlab vs Aforge vs OpenCV

Tags: matlab, image-processing, opencv, aforge

I am about to start a project in visual image-processing and have no had experience with Matlab, Aforge, OpenCV  and was wondering if anyone had any experiences with these different software packages.

I was also wondering which of the three packages were most efficient I assume OpenCV but has anyone had any experience?

Thanks

Jamie.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The question you need to ask yourself is which is more important - your time or the computer's time.  If your task is really simple, you may be able to code it up in MATLAB and have it work right off the bat.  MATLAB is by far the easiest for development - a scripted language with built-in memory management, a huge array of provided functions, and a great interface for displaying and manipulating data while debugging.

On the other hand, MATLAB is at least an order of magnitude slower than compiled openCV code for many tasks.  This is especially true if you use the intel performance primitives libraries.

If you know how to code in MATLAB, I would suggest writing and debugging your algorithms in that language, then porting them to c/c++ with openCV for speed.  If there are only a couple of simple functions that you need to speed up, you can call c code from MATLAB, but it's hard to get this working right the first few times you try it, so you're probably better off just rewriting your finished code entirely in c/c++

Comment: Hey Marc I am completely new to both openCV and matlab and image processing as a whole. I need to do something on eyeball tracking using webcam. What do you recommend? They there ain't enough documentation for openCV?

Answer (score 2):

First, please elaborate about your project's needs. It has the biggest impact on the choice, in addition to other factors - your general programming knowledge (If you haven't dealt with dot net but just with C++, AForge is not a good choice, for example).

Generally,

Both AForge and OpenCV has a built-in interface to .Net, and OpenCV also with C++, python, and more. Matlab might be more efficient, but if you don't have any experience with it - you should also learn its syntax. Take it into consideration.

Matlab probably has the largest variety of functions, but it is more complicated than the other projects. OpenCV and AForge themselves have some differences - see them described in this StackOverflow [question/ answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749241/differences-between-aforge-and-opencv).

Comment: The project involves mounting a camera on the front of a boat travelling down a canal and detecting other boats and objects. Obviously the first problem is dealing with visually processing water.

Answer (score 2):

I worked last year in two similar projects with cars on the highway. Afaik, Matlab allows to process only one picture frame at a time (surely you could elaborate an algorithm to compute a stream) but using Simulink you can process the stream directly.

On the other hand, i found AForge a lot friendlier and easier to use since you can easily adjust the processing parameters from a GUI (not so fast/easy) to do in Matlab/simulink.

I'd go for Aforge.Net. It's also fast enough if you're worrying about processing speed. (using 640x480)

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking about using one of these in .net,easily you can get info by this:

1-matlab mostly used in simulation of projects not the End-prototype project; my numer : 30;

2-aforge (as I'v used in many project) if you do not need the circular process like capturing image, or recognition of something in images or ... you'll find it very good, cause it is easy to use but useful for single processes; my number : 50

3-opencv very good at speed and useful for circular processes, for example you can capture images from a webcam and Instantly cartoonize it without any delay, But not easy-to-use as aforge. I like it anyway cause of its speed and MANY functions it gives us mostly anything we need in programming; my number : 80

Dr.Taha - Tahasoft.net